# Is it possible to add the module path to the python environment variable in linux with out root access?

Tags: python, linux, svn

I am trying to utilise `mailer.py` script to send mails after a SVN Commit. In `mailer.py` svn module has been used. I think the svn module is present in `/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib-146/svn-python/svn` and I tried to append it to the sys path using sys.path.append. For once it is getting appended and when I do sys.path I can see the appended path but after that the path is removed and I am getting `import error: No Module named SVN`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your code please

Comment: You can adjust your `PATH` variable by adding `PATH=$PATH:/mypath` to your `~/.bashrc` .. That will append your custom path to the variable whenever `~/.bashrc` is executed (such as a new terminal session or when `source ~/.bashrc` is called)

Comment: This is in mailer.py

sys.path.append('/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib-146/svn-python/svn')
sys.path.append('/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib-146/svn-python/libsvn')
import svn.delta
import svn.repos
import sv.fs
import svn.core


This is the error I am getting while trying to commit:


File "/data/svn/repos/hook-scripts/mailer/mailer.py", line 46, in ?
    import svn.delta
ImportError: No module named svn.delta

Comment: Inside /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib-146/svn-python/svn folder I have core.py,delta.py,repos.py and fs.py
Inside /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib-146/svn-python/libsvn folder there are .so and .pyc and .la files

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question as worded, but as you continue to use python, I'd encourage you to look into virtualenv as that may simplify things a bit (as you can install svn etc. to your virtualenv and not need to worry about root etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Like setting environment variable in bash, if you close session it will be disapear.

So just add `sys.path.append` it will add path in runtime.

Comment: I appended the path in mailer.py itself but still I am getting no module named svn error while trying to commit.